# Chat Application Web Client

Tags: java, kotlin, frameworks

I am currently working on a Client - Server Chat Application written in Kotlin. The Communication is over Sockets. Now i want to code a Web Application for the Client. Right now I am not sure where to start and what Programming Language to use or which frameworks. I've tested a few frameworks like vaadin and jsf but i can't figure out what to use. And the Application should have a Login screen and a Main Page like the Whatsapp web client. I have decent Experience in Java/Kotlin and JavaFX/TornadoFX.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/). They provide server backend and have Kotlin SDK, should fit your needs. Its possible to create free account for small apps.